# Macro will not run when using application.on time method

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run a macro automatically overnight for my company using the task scheduler on windows and application.ontime method. When I run the macro by myself it works perfectly but it will not work for some reason if it is called via the application.ontime function.

Quite annoying as it is making a fully automated process not automated. Could someone help me out? See where there is problems in the code?

The problem before was that it was not passing the `sDate` variables over to the `Importer Sub` so I tried to change that but now I am getting an argument not optional error message instead. Any ideas?

```
Option Explicit
Public wb1 As Workbook
Public wb2 As Workbook
Public r As Range
Public CSVPath As String
Public sProduct As Worksheet
Public sPivot As Worksheet
Public sCSVSheet As Worksheet
Public sAccount As Worksheet
Public sButton As Worksheet
Public sMainSheet As Worksheet
Public sRawData As Worksheet
Public sFileNames As Worksheet
Public sFrontSheet As Worksheet
Public sBankHolidays As Worksheet
Public sMATrades As Worksheet
Public sMAOverview As Worksheet
Public sMarketData As Worksheet
Public sMAFXEffect As Worksheet
Public sDate As String
Public rDate As Double
Public lastRunDate As Date
Public LRow As Integer
Public LRow2 As Integer
Public ARow As Integer
Public sRange As Range
Public Abr As String
Public FixingName As String
Public FixingReport As String
Public X As Variant
Public Y As Double
Public i As Integer
Public k As Integer
Public p As Integer
Public Ccy As String
Public sYear As Long
Public sMonth As Long
Public sDay As Long
Public pt As PivotTable
Public ws As Worksheet
Public wb As Workbook
Public Text As String
Public ActualDate As Long
Public Col As Long

Sub Main()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

SetSheets

sCSVSheet.Visible = True
sPivot.Visible = True
sFileNames.Visible = True
sBankHolidays.Visible = True

If sButton.Range("ManualDateYesNo").Value = "Yes" Then

sDate = sButton.Range("ManualDate").Value
rDate = sButton.Range("ManualDate").Value

DataDeleter

Do While rDate <> DateValue(Date)
If Weekday(sDate) <> 1 And Weekday(sDate) <> 7 And Not IsNumeric(Application.Match(rDate, sBankHolidays.Columns("A:A"), 0)) Then

Importer (sDate)

End If

rDate = rDate + 1
sDate = Format(DateSerial(Year(rDate), Month(rDate), Day(rDate)), "dd/MM/yyyy")
Loop

sButton.Range("ManualDateYesNo").Value = "No"

Else

If Weekday(Date) = 2 Then
sDate = Date - 3
Else
sDate = Date - 1
End If

If Weekday(Date) = 1 Or Weekday(Date) = 7 Then ThisWorkbook.Close False

LRow = sBankHolidays.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

For Each r In sBankHolidays.Range("A2:A" & LRow)
If Weekday(Date) = 2 Then
    If r + 3 = Date Then ThisWorkbook.Close False
Else
    If r + 1 = Date Then ThisWorkbook.Close False
End If
Next

DataDeleter

Importer (sDate)

End If

RefreshPivots

sMainSheet.Columns("C:C").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
sRawData.Columns("E:E").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
sProduct.Columns("C:C").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
sAccount.Columns("D:D").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

Calculate

sCSVSheet.Visible = False
sPivot.Visible = False
sFileNames.Visible = False
sBankHolidays.Visible = False
sFrontSheet.Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.Quit

End Sub

Private Sub Importer(ByRef sDate As String)

'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

SetSheets

sYear = Year(sDate)
sMonth = Month(sDate)
sDay = Day(sDate)

lastRunDate = sPivot.Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Value

sDate = Format(DateSerial(sYear, sMonth, sDay), "yyyyMMdd")
rDate = DateValue(Format(DateSerial(sYear, sMonth, sDay), "dd/MM/yyyy"))

LRow = sFileNames.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

For Each sRange In sFileNames.Range("A2:A" & LRow)

Abr = sRange.Offset(0, 1).Value
FixingName = sRange.Offset(0, 2).Value

FixingReport = "P:\Systemfiles\SharedDocs\" & Abr & "\Fixing Files\" & sDate & " " & FixingName & ".xls"

Workbooks.Open Filename:=FixingReport, ReadOnly:=True

SetSheets2

sMAOverview.Range("D9:D43").Copy

With sProduct
LRow = .Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1

.Range("E" & LRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
.Range("C" & LRow).Value = rDate
.Range("B" & LRow).Value = sRange
.Activate
.Range("A" & LRow - 1).AutoFill Destination:=Range("A" & LRow - 1 & ":A" & LRow)
End With

RefreshPivots

End If

Next

LRow = sPivot.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

LRow = sMAFXEffect.Columns("B:B").Find("DBIN", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
LRow2 = sMAFXEffect.Range("B65000").End(xlUp).Row

k = LRow

For Each r In sMAFXEffect.Range("B" & LRow & ":B" & LRow2)
sMAFXEffect.Activate
sMAFXEffect.Range(Cells(k, 3), Cells(k, 11)).Copy

With sAccount
LRow = .Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
.Activate
.Range("E" & LRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Ccy = .Range("M" & LRow).Value
ARow = sMAFXEffect.Columns("B:B").Find(Ccy, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
.Range("O" & LRow).Value = sMAFXEffect.Cells(ARow, 11).Value
.Range("D" & LRow).Value = rDate
.Range("C" & LRow).Value = r
.Range("Q" & LRow).Value = sRange
.Activate
.Range("A" & LRow - 1 & ":B" & LRow - 1).AutoFill Destination:=Range("A" & LRow - 1 & ":B" & LRow)
.Range("P" & LRow - 1).AutoFill Destination:=Range("P" & LRow - 1 & ":P" & LRow)
.Range("N" & LRow - 1).AutoFill Destination:=Range("N" & LRow - 1 & ":N" & LRow)
'.Range("N" & LRow).Value = .Range("E" & LRow).Value * .Range("O" & LRow).Value
k = k + 1
End With
Next

wb2.Close False

Next

For Each pt In sPivot.PivotTables
    pt.PivotCache.Refresh
Next

With sPivot
LRow = .Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
rDate = .Range("A" & LRow).Value
LRow = .Range("I1048576").End(xlUp).Row
End With

For Each r In sPivot.Range("I3:I" & LRow)
With sRawData
.Activate
LRow = .Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
.Range("D" & LRow).Value = r
.Range("C" & LRow).Value = r.Offset(0, 1).Value
.Range("E" & LRow).Value = rDate
.Range("A" & LRow - 1).AutoFill Destination:=Range("A" & LRow - 1 & ":A" & LRow)
.Range("B" & LRow - 1).AutoFill Destination:=Range("B" & LRow - 1 & ":B" & LRow)
.Range("F" & LRow - 1 & ":CB" & LRow - 1).AutoFill Destination:=Range("F" & LRow - 1 & ":CB" & LRow)
If .Range("K" & LRow).Value = 0 Then .Range("K" & LRow).EntireRow.Delete

If .Range("J" & LRow).Value = "True" Then
Text = .Range("C" & LRow).Text & .Range("D" & LRow).Text & CDbl(.Range("F" & LRow).Value)
X = Application.Match(Text, .Columns("A:A"), 0)
.Range("S" & LRow).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("AK" & X)
End If

End With
Next

LRow = sPivot.Range("L1048576").End(xlUp).Row

For Each r In sPivot.Range("L3:L" & LRow)
With sMainSheet
.Activate
LRow = .Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1
.Range("B" & LRow).Value = r
.Range("C" & LRow).Value = rDate
.Range("A" & LRow - 1).AutoFill Destination:=Range("A" & LRow - 1 & ":A" & LRow)
.Range("D" & LRow - 1 & ":BP" & LRow - 1).AutoFill Destination:=Range("D" & LRow - 1 & ":BP" & LRow)
.Range("BB" & LRow).ClearContents
.Range("BB" & LRow).Value = .Range("AW" & LRow).Value
End With
Next

sButton.Range("LastRun").Value = rDate

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

For Each wb In Workbooks
If wb.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then wb.Close False
Next

MsgBox Err.Description & Err.Source

End Sub

Public Sub DataDeleter()

For Each ws In wb1.Worksheets
On Error Resume Next
If ws.Name = "Main Sheet" Or ws.Name = "Raw Data" Or ws.Name = "Product" Or ws.Name = "Account" Then
Col = Sheets(ws.Name).Rows("1:1").Find("Date", lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column
X = Application.Match(rDate, Sheets(ws.Name).Columns(Col), 0)
LRow = Sheets(ws.Name).Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets(ws.Name).Rows(X & ":" & LRow).EntireRow.Delete
End If
On Error GoTo 0
Next

End Sub

Public Sub RefreshPivots()

For Each ws In Worksheets
    For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
        pt.PivotCache.Refresh
    Next
Next

End Sub

Public Sub SetSheets()

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook

Set sProduct = wb1.Sheets("Product")
Set sPivot = wb1.Sheets("Pivot")
Set sCSVSheet = wb1.Sheets("CSVSheet")
Set sAccount = wb1.Sheets("Account")
Set sButton = wb1.Sheets("Button Sheet")
Set sRawData = wb1.Sheets("Raw Data")
Set sMainSheet = wb1.Sheets("Main Sheet")
Set sFileNames = wb1.Sheets("File Names")
Set sFrontSheet = wb1.Sheets("Front Sheet")
Set sBankHolidays = wb1.Sheets("Bank Holidays")

End Sub
Public Sub SetSheets2()

Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook

Set sMATrades = wb2.Sheets("MA Trades")
Set sMAOverview = wb2.Sheets("MA Overview")
Set sMarketData = wb2.Sheets("Market Data")
Set sMAFXEffect = wb2.Sheets("MA FX Effect")

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the OnTime call in your code?

Comment: It is in the ThisWorkbook 'Sheet' with code Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.OnTime TimeValue("09:20:30"), "Importer"

End Sub

Comment: Importer expects a parameter that you're not passing into your call.

Comment: Could you explain further?

Comment: In your code you wrote: `Private Sub Importer(ByRef sDate As String)`. Which means, the Sub Importer has to start with a parameter called `sDate`. However, your OnTime call is `Application.OnTime TimeValue("09:20:30"), "Importer"`. The parameter `sDate` is not passed in this call, so the run fails with message `Argument not optional`.

Comment: Ahhh I see, completely missed that. What I have done is altered the shape of the macro midway through coding it and not changer the "Importer" on the ontime back to "Main". Thank you for your help!

Comment: well my question got answered so...

Comment: No problem. To make it an mcve (as the question could anyway help other people), as @pnuts suggests, please remove all the code and let only the relevant parts (i.e. the Application On Time call on a side, and the Private Sub declaration on the other side). Then you might add your answer to the post so that anyone having the same problem of your in the future will find this thread helpful.

Comment: I don't see why you're saying it isn't an mcve post. Everything required of an mcve post is in there. Downvoting someone on their first post which instantly got answered seems like a bit of a dickish thing to do tbh

Comment: Obviously the question won't help others, it wasn't a problem with the code, it was me being retarded and calling the wrong macro. That's not going to help anyone

Comment: It's not about you, it's about the content. @pnuts doesn't know you, but knows the community standards and is just suggesting to follow the "M" (minimal) part of the mcve definition to comply with those standards. Don't get upset (and please don't be offensive to other users), SO is a source of info for all developers so your question might definitely be helpful because many developers make the Application On Time call wrong because not passing a compulsory parameter. Please edit your question accordingly and add your answer, I'm sure who gave you the downvote will revoke it.

Comment: I don't think suggesting that someone was being dickish is offensive. I just think its a bit unfair, unfortunately I've lost my log in for my other account as it was on a previous companies email but I had asked many many questions exactly like this before and not been persecuted. I asked a question and it got answered very quickly and it's obvious what the problem was. I posted alot of code because on this community people get mad at you if you don't. Absurd that I'm being downvoted for it frankly. I'll post the answer but saying 'I was calling the wrong macro' isn't going to help

Comment: I think you really take it too much on the personal side. That's fine you've solved your problem. The only thing I was trying to do is to make the post helpful to others in the spirit of SO

Comment: I'm only taking it personally because I'm being downvoted. I couldn't care less otherwise

Comment: Your question is getting downvoted, not you. Never mind, the important thing is that your problem is solved now. I'm going to make the edit to your question, if you don't like it just revert it pleae.

Answer (score 0):

It happened that upon redesigning my code, I hadn't changed the application.ontime upon opening the workbook to call a different macro. I changed the macro it called and now it works

Comment: This isn't the answer though, the answer was that I was trying to call the Importer directly rather than calling the 'Main' sub first which in turn calls the Importer, if you looked at the code the paramater is passed in the call. By deleting my code you've completely taken away the context.

Comment: Ok, I give up. I've reverted all.